# Ubuntu after Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot

So, I was thinking about installing Windows 10 on a already Ubuntu 20.04 machine, and I was wondering, if I can boot into Ubuntu after installing Windows 10.

Comment: there are many good guides using google, here is one>>>https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/

Comment: What is the computer model, and specifically are you using EFI?

Comment: Can you add another HDD?

Comment: @user3169 I have a primary 150 GB Intel SSD and a 80 GB HDD

Comment: @harrymc I am not sure about EFI, I can tell you, i have an Athlon X2 64 4200+ and a ATI Radeon 6000 HD with 4 GB of DDR2 420 mHz RAM

Comment: @Moab that is the other way, I am not installing Ubuntu 20.04 on a already Windows 10 machine. I am trying to install Windows 10 on a already Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

Comment: I think the safest method is disconnect the Ubuntu OS drive, then install Windows on the other drive. Reconnect it after confirming the Windows install. Worst case you can select OS by drive boot order selection in BIOS, but Ubuntu GRUB might update automatically, otherwise update manually. Also this way you don't have to mess with which partition is which.

Answer (score 0):

This CPU is pretty old, dating perhaps from 2006, so the computer surely does not use
EFI. This means that installing Windows 10 will install the Windows bootloader
to boot directly into Windows, which you will need to fix later.

But first some cautions: Windows 10 is a large OS and may be a bit slow on your
computer. Second, ensure you have Windows 10 drivers for all your devices
before starting, because Windows 10 might be missing some of them.

For fixing GRUB boot after installing Windows 10, see the article
[How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: I had installed windows 10 on this pc before, so no worries for that regard, all i care about is, id i can boot into ubuntu after windows is installed

Comment: You will be able to, after re-establishing Grub as the bootloader, as in the linked post.

Comment: if i can reinstall grub without doing anything to the install

Comment: Repairing Grub will only apply to grub.